# Ajax not working in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am trying to build a form with Ajax functionality for a Wordpress plugin. A jQuery function is being called but no response is being displayed.

Here is the **Ajax code**

```
function ajaxformschool() {
    var id = "Hello World";
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxschoolajax.ajaxurl,
        action: 'ajaxschool_process',
        data: {"data":id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            jQuery("#comment").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Front end and registering Ajax Code**

```
function ajaxschool_enqueuescripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('ajaxschool', ASSFURL. '/js/ajaxschool.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_localize_script('ajaxschool', 'ajaxschoolajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php')));
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', ajaxschool_enqueuescripts);
<form>
    echo '<a onclick="ajaxformschool();" style="cursor: pointer"><b>Search</b></a>';
    echo '<div id="comment"></div>';
</form>
```

**Ajax Function Action**

```
function ajaxschool_process() {
    $response="thanks everythong is ok";
    echo json_encode($response);
    die($response);
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxschool_process', 'ajaxschool_process' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajaxschool_process', 'ajaxschool_process' );
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to add `action` property in data field of jquery ajax function.

**Ajax code**

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxschoolajax.ajaxurl,    
        data: {"data":id,'action':'ajaxschool_process'}, //MY CHANGE
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            jQuery("#comment").html(data);
    }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the HTML for the form

```
<form type="post" action="" id="newCustomerForm">

<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input name="name" type="text" />

<label for="email">Email:</label>
<input name="email" type="text" />

<label for="phone">Phone:</label>
<input name="phone" type="text" />

<label for="address">Address:</label>
<input name="address" type="text" />

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="addCustomer"/>
<input type="submit">
</form>
<br/><br/>
<div id="feedback"></div>
```

Next, open up functions.php and add the following line to ensure jQuery is being loaded on your site:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
//The basic structure for writing an AJAX call is as follows:

function myFunction(){
//do something
die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_myFunction', 'myFunction');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myFunction', 'myFunction');
```

Finally the javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#newCustomerForm').submit(ajaxSubmit);

function ajaxSubmit(){

var newCustomerForm = jQuery(this).serialize();

jQuery.ajax({
type:"POST",
url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
data: newCustomerForm,
success:function(data){
jQuery("#feedback").html(data);
}
});

return false;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, there is no need to both `echo` and `exit` (or `die`) at the same time, since both `exit` and `die` will echo out the response. I have included important changes to the Ajax process function...

```
function ajaxschool_process() {
    $response = "Thanks. Everything is ok.";
    exit(json_encode($response));
}
```